# How to align items from start in a Flex Layout of xamarin forms?

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin forms V3.3.0. I am not able to align items in the last row of a flex layout from start. I tried with these property combination, Direction="Row"  Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="Center" AlignContent="Start"  AlignItems="Start". Added code and image below.

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row"  Wrap="Wrap" Margin="5" JustifyContent="Center"  AlignContent="Start"  AlignItems="Start">
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>
            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="5"></BoxView>            
        </FlexLayout>
```

[image: see the image here]

Answer (score 0):

For these item on the last line, the `JustifyContent="Center"` is all the items are moved to the center.

You could try using `JustifyContent="Start"` instead:

[image]

Comment: I already tried that but I need to maintain equal margins for start and end of the flex layout in all devices. In the image you shared the right margin is more than the left margin.

Comment: Then the bottom two boxes need to be wider, which FlexLayout won't do for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you flexlayout to this:

```
<FlexLayout WidthRequest="330" HorizontalOptions="Center"  Wrap="Wrap" Margin="5">
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

`JustifyContent="Start"` cause empty space on right.I solved the empty space problem as follows: First of all, you need to determine how many frames you want on the screen, for example, let's assume there will be 3 columns Then we can arrange frame widths according to screenWidht/3 so we can use Xamarin.Essentials to calculate.You can bind FrameWidthValue to FrameWidth in constructor.

```
       double screenWidth = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width;     
       double density = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
       DisplayOrientation orientation = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation;


     
           FrameWidthValue = (((screenWidth / density)) * 1 / 3);
```

In this way, a solution similar to the grid but more responsive than the grid was produced.